How to scale objects keeping them in their own position
I need to scale all those red circles keeping them  in thier respective position. It takes a lot of time if I wanna do it individially, I tried selct thema all and scale 50% to reduce them but all of them lose their own position and accumulate and ended up in weird place. Is there any way where I can keep them all in their own position and also scale them to reduce their size. Thank you.



Have you tried Object -> Transform -> Transform Each? This will apply a transform to each object but change from it's original spot on the artboard.

:O :O :O Thank you so much!!! I didnt know it. Thank you.

That's an answer @AndrewH

You can transform each object based on it's origin/anchor point. To do this, go to Object -> Transform -> Transform Each.
